# How to add new columns in dataframe in for loop in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I read data from an excel file, it is like this:
[Que](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpkyN.png)

It is in a data frame format.I want the modified data frame as below:

```
Sem1  Sem2   Sem3  
50     36     28

45     41     47

50     48     43
```

I have used below code:

`for f in lparameters:
        print("Creating Column:" ,f)
        df_temp[f]=dfs["Total"].get_group(f)`

But this code the only one (first column).

Please help me out !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = df.set_index([df.groupby('Sem').cumcount(), 'Sem'])['Total'].unstack()
print (df)
Sem  Sem2  Sem3  Seml
0      36    28    50
1      41    47    45
2      48    43    50
```

Another solution is create `list` per group and then use `DataFrame` constructor:

```
a = df.groupby('Sem')['Total'].apply(list)
df = pd.DataFrame(a.values.tolist(), index=a.index).T
print (df)
Sem  Sem2  Sem3  Seml
0      36    28    50
1      41    47    45
2      48    43    50
```